# I have deployed Magento in heroku all is fine until i encounter this error

Tags: magento2, database

[image]

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  for the database server host name 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Comment: It has not worked parekh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something error with your database credential

as per your image that is what I understand May be you have written wrong db credential

check list for you

> Create Db user at your server
>
> Set password for that user
>
> Create Blank database

and put those right credential at here

Comment: Thank you Murtuza,but I can do all those things locally with xampp server.but i have no idea how to do that in heroku.when i deployed magento2 to heroku ,it just showed me that client interface

Comment: @vignesh as per your image I think you are trying this at live site

Comment: yes murtuza,I am in cloud environment

Comment: @vignesh how can you connect your local database with cloud  ?? create database at your cloud environment

Comment: yes murtuza,i thought that heroku would provide mysql default for the deployed application.but it wont provide mysql it seems.can you suggest me a way to implement database for magento in heroku

Comment: @vignesh So create your database at any live server and fill those live database server detail at here

Comment: @vignesh if this answer help you then here is an option to accept answer , so accept the answer so if someone who has same problem take benifit from it

Comment: yeah ok murtuza

Comment: Not sure why this answer is accepted. If it is hosted on Heroku node it clearly doesn't have MySQL installed on the same server. It's not the credentials, it is that the MySQL server is going to be hosted on a different IP not localhost/127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe Heroku uses database urls to convey the DB connection information that it has configured.  you can use heroku config --app APPNAME to get the connection url which you can then enter in the web install wizard.